# Using Case When in SQL Server 2008 within the query containing multiple value for same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        ISNULL(dbo.sav_acc_mcg.group_id, '0') AS group_id ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status ,
        ISNULL(dbo.sav_acc_mcg.center_id, '0') AS center_id ,
        st.acc_no AS acc_number ,
        ( SELECT    scheme_name
          FROM      mau_sav_scheme
          WHERE     scheme_id = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.scheme_id
        ) AS schemeName ,
        ISNULL(( SELECT alias
                 FROM   mem_group_mcg
                 WHERE  group_id = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.group_id
               ), '') AS group_name ,
        ISNULL(( SELECT alias
                 FROM   mem_group_mcg
                 WHERE  group_id = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.center_id
               ), '') AS int_group_name ,
        ISNULL(( SELECT ( SUM(sav_amt) - SUM(wthdrl_amt) ) AS cur_bal
                 FROM   dbo.sav_transaction
                 WHERE  trxn_dt < '1966-07-23'
                        AND acc_no = st.acc_no
                        AND trxn_id <= trxn_id
               ), '0') AS alya ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no_alias
FROM    dbo.sav_transaction AS st
        INNER JOIN dbo.sav_acc_mcg ON st.acc_no = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no
WHERE   ( dbo.sav_acc_mcg.scheme_id = '007' )
        AND ( st.trxn_dt BETWEEN '1966-07-23' AND '2014-01-15' )
        AND dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1'
GROUP BY dbo.sav_acc_mcg.center_id ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.group_id ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.scheme_id ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no ,
        st.acc_no ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no_alias
ORDER BY int_group_name ,
        group_name ,
        acc_number
```

And the problem is that the condition "`and dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1'`" must  dynamically change to "`and (dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1' or dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '3'`)" depending upon particular acc_number . The changing data of the acc_number comes from another table; which is a date, such that if the date is not within the range of the upper limit of "`st.trxn_dt`" , then the condition should change to `(dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1' or dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '3')`, else  it should be `dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1'`.
Also I have to get the date of particular `acc_no` from another table to compare the date range. The query for getting the date is :

```
SELECT  ISNULL(updated_dt, '') AS updt_dt
FROM    sav_acc_mcg
WHERE   acc_no = '006000014'
```

Here the field `acc_no` should be fetched from the previous query.
This checking should only be carried out for the `acc_no` whose  `dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '3'`
How to acheive this using sql query ?
Help is greatly appreciated.
The upper limit and lower limit of the date range is from java code(user input).

I modified the query like this :

```
DECLARE @upperLmt DATE
SET @upperLmt = '2014-01-15'
SELECT DISTINCT
        ISNULL(dbo.sav_acc_mcg.group_id, '0') AS group_id ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status ,
        ISNULL(dbo.sav_acc_mcg.center_id, '0') AS center_id ,
        st.acc_no AS acc_number ,
        ( SELECT    scheme_name
          FROM      mau_sav_scheme
          WHERE     scheme_id = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.scheme_id
        ) AS schemeName ,
        ISNULL(( SELECT alias
                 FROM   mem_group_mcg
                 WHERE  group_id = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.group_id
               ), '') AS group_name ,
        ISNULL(( SELECT alias
                 FROM   mem_group_mcg
                 WHERE  group_id = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.center_id
               ), '') AS int_group_name ,
        ISNULL(( SELECT ( SUM(sav_amt) - SUM(wthdrl_amt) ) AS cur_bal
                 FROM   dbo.sav_transaction
                 WHERE  trxn_dt < '1966-07-23'
                        AND acc_no = st.acc_no
                        AND trxn_id <= trxn_id
               ), '0') AS alya ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no_alias
FROM    dbo.sav_transaction AS st
        INNER JOIN dbo.sav_acc_mcg ON st.acc_no = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no
WHERE   ( dbo.sav_acc_mcg.scheme_id = '007' )
        AND ( st.trxn_dt BETWEEN '1966-07-23' AND @upperLmt ) AND
       -- AND dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1'
                (CASE WHEN dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '3' THEN
(CASE WHEN sav_acc_mcg.updated_dt > @upperLmt THEN ( dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1' AND dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '3')
ELSE ( dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1' )
END)
ELSE (dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1')
END)
GROUP BY dbo.sav_acc_mcg.center_id ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.group_id ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.scheme_id ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no ,
        st.acc_no ,
        dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no_alias
ORDER BY int_group_name ,
        group_name ,
        acc_number
```

But didn't work.

Comment: That's a lot to wade through mate, you might get more help if you can do a sql fiddle for it. If it were me I'd break it up in to some well named CTEs, imagine coming back and having to twiddle with this in 6 months time.

Comment: Try cleaning up the question. You dont need the last sql bit about getting the updated_dt. The query already has that table and therefore that column. Of these dates (updated_dt, trxn_dt, upperlimit, lowerlimit), what needs to be compared to what to determine if status = 3 should be used?

Comment: I modified the query like this :

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "sav_acc_mcg" table in the inner join, and later you can use the case statement like this:

```
Case 
when sav_acc_mcg.acc_number = 'some value' then (dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1') 
when sav_acc_mcg.acc_number = 'some other value' then (dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '3')
else (dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '1') 
end
```

hope it will defintely work

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand which dates need to be compared to which other dates. Try to clarify that in the question and we can answer better. For now, your query needs to be cleaned up a bit ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        ISNULL(sam.group_id, '0') AS group_id ,
        sam.status ,
        ISNULL(sam.center_id, '0') AS center_id ,
        st.acc_no AS acc_number ,
        mss.scheme_name AS schemeName ,
        ISNULL(mgm_gn.alias, '') AS group_name,
        ISNULL(mgm_ign.alias, '') AS int_group_name,
        ISNULL(( SELECT ( SUM(sav_amt) - SUM(wthdrl_amt) ) AS cur_bal
                 FROM   sav_transaction
                 WHERE  trxn_dt < '1966-07-23'
                        AND acc_no = st.acc_no
                        AND trxn_id <= trxn_id
               ), '0') AS alya ,
        sam.acc_no_alias
FROM    sav_transaction AS st
        INNER JOIN sav_acc_mcg as sam ON st.acc_no = sam.acc_no
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mem_group_mcg mgm_gn ON mgm_gn.group_id = sam.group_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mem_group_mcg mgm_ign ON mgm_ign.group_id = sam.center_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN mau_sav_scheme mss ON mss.scheme_id = sam.scheme_id
WHERE   sam.scheme_id = '007'
        AND st.trxn_dt BETWEEN '1966-07-23' AND '2014-01-15'
        AND sam.status = '1'
GROUP BY sam.center_id ,
        sam.group_id ,
        sam.scheme_id ,
        sam.acc_no ,
        st.acc_no ,
        sam.acc_no_alias                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
ORDER BY int_group_name ,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        group_name ,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        acc_number
```

Answer (score 0):

I did get the desired result using this query :

```
SELECT distinct     st.acc_no AS acc_number, 
sum(st.sav_amt) AS Saving,  sum(st.wthdrl_amt) AS Withdrawl, 
isnull((select alias from mem_group_mcg where group_id = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.group_id), '') as group_name,
 isnull((select alias from mem_group_mcg where group_id = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.center_id), '') as int_group_name, 
dbo.sav_acc_mcg.center_id,
 dbo.sav_acc_mcg.group_id,
 dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no_alias 
FROM dbo.sav_transaction AS st 
 INNER JOIN dbo.sav_acc_mcg ON st.acc_no = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no 
INNER JOIN dbo.mau_sav_scheme ON dbo.mau_sav_scheme.scheme_id = dbo.sav_acc_mcg.scheme_id
 WHERE (dbo.mau_sav_scheme.scheme_id= '007') AND(st.trxn_dt BETWEEN '1966-07-23' AND '2014-01-15') and 
dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status  LIKE
 (CASE WHEN dbo.sav_acc_mcg.status = '3' THEN
(CASE WHEN sav_acc_mcg.updated_dt >= '2014-01-15' THEN ( '[13]%')
ELSE ( '1' )
END)
ELSE ('1')
END) 
group by st.acc_no, dbo.sav_acc_mcg.group_id, dbo.sav_acc_mcg.center_id, dbo.sav_acc_mcg.acc_no_alias 
order by dbo.sav_acc_mcg.center_id , dbo.sav_acc_mcg.group_id
```